# Waypoints malfunction upon AJAX Page Load

Tags: ajax, wordpress, offset, jquery-waypoints

I'm hoping this is a known issue that there is a fix for. This is driving me nuts!

I'm using Waypoints to trigger both the posts and the fixed nav. When 40% of the post enters the viewport, a class is added to the post to change the scale and a class is added to the associated categories in the nav to change the opacity.

If you go the site, it works great. But if you click "Wordpress" in the nav, the page will load via AJAX.

The problem is... when the post reaches the point where Waypoint should be triggered, the nav is triggered but the post is not. If you continue to scroll, the posts a triggered the OPPOSITE of when and where they should be.

I added debug.js and get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Context' of undefined(…)
checkWaypointStyles @ debug.js?ver=20151215:16(anonymous function) @ debug.js?ver=20151215:38(anonymous function) @ debug.js?

http://portfolio.cairndigitalmedia.com/

```
//  Waypoint effects on posts   

$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').addClass('post-visible'); 
}, {
offset: '60%'
});
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').addClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '0%'
});
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').removeClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '100%'
}); 
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(even)').removeClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '-40%'
});  


$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').addClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '60%'
});
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').addClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '0%'
});
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').removeClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '100%'
}); 
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').waypoint(function() {
$('#main > .post:nth-child(odd)').removeClass('post-visible');
}, {
offset: '-40%'
}); 


// Waypoint effects on nav

$('.post.category-wordpress').waypoint(function() {
$('li.wordpress a').addClass('category-visible');
}, {
offset: '60%'
});
$('.post.category-wordpress').waypoint(function() {
$('li.wordpress a').addClass('category-visible');
}, {
offset: '0%'
});
$('.post.category-wordpress').waypoint(function() {
$('li.wordpress a').removeClass('category-visible');
}, {
offset: '70%'
});
$('.post.category-wordpress').waypoint(function() {
$('li.wordpress a').removeClass('category-visible');
}, {
offset: '-40%'
});
```

Comment: I figured this out. Not a Waypoint issue at all. When I loaded the archive page, the category title was inside #main instead of above it like on the home page.